# how to set nginx index

Tags: nginx, node.js, meteor

Here is a service `http://example.com` based on port 4000 service, I can visit `http://example.com/index.html` now. When I visit `http://example.com`, I want it visit `index.html` too.  Here is my nginx settings:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com ;

    location / {
      root  /wwwroot/product/example.com/programs/web.broswer/app;
      index index.html;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;         # 映射到本地端口
      #proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # 配置支持websocket
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Now, the path `/` is not the resources of `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `index` directive will not work with a `proxy_pass` location. However, you can explicitly map `/` to `/index.html` with an exact match location, using:

```
location = / { rewrite ^ /index.html; }
```

to perform an internal redirect, or:

```
location = / { return 301 /index.html; }
```

to perform an external redirect.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) for details.